# Como enviar um objeto por parâmetro?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, parâmetros, java-bean

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="agencia" converter="agenciasConverter"
                 value="#{agenciasMB.agencias.agencia}" style="width:150px">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a Agência" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{agenciasMB.lista}" var="org" 
                   itemValue="#{org}" itemLabel="#{org.agencia}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:fileUpload id="fileIdPhoto" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false"
              fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.uploadPhoto}" fileLimit="3" 
              multiple="true" update="messages" sizeLimit="10000000000" 
              label="Escolha o arquivo" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/">  
    <f:attribute name="agencia" value="#{org}" />
</p:fileUpload>
```

Como passar o objeto `agência` selecionada e recuperar em `fileUploadBean.uploadPhoto`?

---

Eu fazia assim pra recuperar uma variável:

```
<f:attribute name="agencia" value="minhavariavel" />
```

No *ManagedBean*:

```
e.getComponent().getAttributes().get("agencia")
```

---

Como usar o **`f:attribute`** para passar objeto que foi selecionado no `select` para o *backbean*?

Comment: Já experimentou criar um método que receba este objeto ou algum atributo no qual você possa setá-lo?

Answer (score 3):

### Há **quatro** maneiras de você passar um objeto como parâmetro via JSF:

---

#### 1. Desde a versão 2.0 do JSF você pode passar parâmetros diretamente:

Página XHTML:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{testeBean.testarParametroString('Parâmetro Enviado')}" />
<h:commandButton action="#{testeBean.testarParametroNumero(2016)}" />
<h:commandButton action="#{testeBean.testarParametroObjeto(carro)}" />
// O botão pode estar dentro de uma tabela de objetos do tipo carro
```

BackBean:

```
public void testarParametroString(String palavra) {
    System.out.println(">>> Verificando parâmetro recebido: " + palavra);
}

public void testarParametroNumero(Integer numero) {
    System.out.println(">>> Verificando parâmetro recebido: " + numero);
}

public void testarParametroObjeto(Carro carro) {
    System.out.println(">>> Verificando parâmetro recebido: " + carro);
}
```

*Observação: Se você utiliza Tomcat tenha certeza de incluir a biblioteca: el-impl-2.2.jar*

---

#### 2. Passando parâmetros via `f:param`

Página XHTML:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{testeBean.testar}">
    <f:param name="parametro" value="Parâmetro Enviado" />
</h:commandButton>
```

BackBean:

```
public void testar() {
    Map<String,String> p = FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String parametroRecebido = p.get("parametro");
    System.out.println(">>> Verificando parâmetro recebido: " + parametroRecebido);
}
```

---

#### 3. Passando parâmetros via `f:atribute`

Página XHTML:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{testeBean.executarAcao}" actionListener="#{testeBean.testar}">
    <f:attribute name="parametro" value="testandoParametro" />
</h:commandButton>
```

BackBean:

```
public void testar(ActionEvent event) {
    String parametroRecebido;
    parametroRecebido = (String) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("parametro");
}

public void executarAcao() {
    //Ação a ser realizada ao clicar no botão...
}
```

---

#### 4. Passando parâmetros via `f:setPropertyActionListener`

Página XHTML:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{testeBean.testar}" >
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{testeBean.parametro}" value="Teste" />
</h:commandButton>
```

BackBean:

```
public String parametro;

public void testar() {
    //Ação a ser realizada ao clicar no botão...
}

public void setParametro(String parametroRecebido) {
    this.parametro = parametroRecebido;
}
```

---

#### Mais informações:

- http://www.javaavancado.com/3-passos-como-passar-parametros-por-url-em-jsf/
- https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/4-ways-to-pass-parameter-from-jsf-page-to-backing-bean/